# Problems trying to access to a global var

Tags: python, global-variables, scope

I know how to use the global variables when they are defined in a class, but I have a global variable in a main.
If I want to use it inside a class, which would be the import to access it?

My main is something like this

Main.py:

```
from EvolutionaryAlgorithm import EvolutionaryAlgorithm
initialTimeMain = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    evolutionaryAlgorithm= EvolutionaryAlgorithm()
.
.
```

and my EvolutionaryAlgorithm class has a method which uses the initialTimeMain variable.
the problem is when I add this import in the EvolutionaryAlgorithm:

EvolutionaryAlgorithm.py

```
import Main
```

because when I run the script, an error appears

> from EvolutionaryAlgorithm import
>   EvolutionaryAlgorithm ImportError:
>   cannot import name
>   EvolutionaryAlgorithm

the import isn't recognized anymore

Comment: What did you try?  Which imports did you try and what were the results.  The question itself isn't dumb.  But please, please, please, try something and post the code you tried before asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a case of circular imports, short-term solution is to move import statement inside the if clause:

```
initialTimeMain = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from EvolutionaryAlgorithm import EvolutionaryAlgorithm
    evolutionaryAlgorithm= EvolutionaryAlgorithm()
```

A better, long-term solution would be to refactor your code so that you don't have circular imports or `initialTimeMain` is defined in the `EvolutionaryAlgorithm.py`, which of course would be available in `Main.py` with your existing import strategy.

Old answer:

```
a.py:

globalvar = 1
print(globalvar)             # prints 1
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(globalvar)         # prints 1

b.py:

import a
print(a.globalvar)           # prints 1
```

Comment: @Federico: import main? what do you mean?

Comment: @Federico: Please update your question with the code that doesn't work.  And please be very, very clear on "can't run the code".  What does that mean?

Comment: I mean import the Main.py which has a main

Comment: why do I have a -3 in my question?

Comment: @Federico: you have -2 at the moment, I suppose a couple of people didn't think your question unclear or not useful. I'd think it was before you posted clarification.